# unable to connect the remote controller at 127.0.0.1:6633

Tags: controller, sdn, opendaylight

I want to connect mininet to ODL controller:oxygen but when I start the mininet with this command:sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1,port=6633,--topo tree,depth=3, it is shown that, unable to connect the controller at 127.0.0.1:6633 and unable to connect the controller at 127.0.0.1:6653.
I have installed odl-l2switch-switch,odl-restconfe,odl-dlux-core and odl-mdsal and many other controller features already. I can access to dlux via my web browser but as I said mininet did not connect to the controller. I also checked open ports 6633 and 6653 and they were not listed.
please help!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If ports 6633 and 6653 are not open on your opendaylight system, then openflowplugin did not start properly. Can you check in karaf.log for any error messages or clues? If you are installing l2switch, that will automatically install openflowplugin.

btw, you must be using an older version of ODL, since l2switch is no longer available in recent releases. just a warning in case you try with a newer version.

Comment: I have installed ODL:Beryllium , i have also installed openflowplugin , mininet connected to controller on port 6653 but nothing was shown on dlux and hosts are unable to ping each other in mininet.

Comment: sorry, not enough info to help. originally you said you installed l2switch. now it's just openflowplugin? seems like you have dlux installed too if you are trying to use that. did you check karaf.log like I suggested? can you see if the openflow ports are open and listening on the ODL system (6633 and 6653). on a linux or osx system you can use the netstat command to check.

Comment: I installed l2switch,mdsal-apidocs,dlux-core,openflowplugin and ...  i checked the karaf.log there was no problem. I also checked the open ports and 6633 was open. "connecting to port 6633 on 127.0.0.1" was shown in mininet but when I wrote pingall command hosts can not answer to that

Comment: can you run 'sudo ovs-vsctl show' on the mininet system to see if it shows openvswitch as "is connected: true"? if that's shown as connected, then maybe you are hitting some bug? I vaguely remember there being some bugs around l2switch. you can try to clean the environment and restart the controller. stop ODL then 'rm -rf' on the data/ journal/ snapshot/ and cache/ folders. Put your features in the featuresBoot variable instead of installing from karaf console. then start ODL again. Either way, keep posting what you find and I can try to help you get it working.

Comment: Thank you for your helping. I reckon, I found the solution. I used ODL:Beryllium and I used sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1 --mac --topo=linear,3 --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13. But I guess controller or mininet does not support protocol=OpenFlow13 so I use sudo mn --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1 --mac --topo=linear,3 --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow10 instead of that command and everything is working now. I hope that it is solved the problem.

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-70" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected state: HANDSHAKING, actual state:RIP
 at org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.openflow.md.core.ConnectionConductorImpl.checkState(ConnectionConductorImpl.java:386)
 at org.opendaylight.openflowplugin.openflow.md.core.ConnectionConductorImpl.onConnectionReady(ConnectionConductorImpl.java:448)
 at org.opendaylight.openflowjava.protocol.impl.core.connection.ConnectionAdapterImpl$1.run(ConnectionAdapterImpl.java:185)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)            these errors is shown but hosts can still ping eachother.

Comment: I forgot to say that I installed odl-mdsal-XSQL too.

Comment: no, openflow 1.3 should be supported just fine, but it's weird that you made it work with
just version 1.0. Is it possible that your OVS system does not work with v1.3. You could
check the ovs logs to see what messages are in there to give more clues.

Comment: I checked it now and it is working with openflow 1.3 and I have no idea why this is happening.